# Would it be illegal to sell a drone defense system to a nation under an arms embargo?

Tags: international, weapons, sanctions, drones

Will it be illegal to sell anti-drone systems to any nation like Gaza? Because it's not a weapon system, it's more like a defensive technology. Would it still violate an arms embargo?

Comment: A defensive weapon is still a weapon.

Comment: Each arms embargo is different.

Answer (score 7):

In the US, it is illegal to sell screwdrivers to Gaza without a license, see 31 [CFR 595.409](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=0ab6651e369798de0dd2faae265ded08&mc=true&node=se31.3.595_1409&rgn=div8). There are numerous rules pertaining to the Palestinian Authority staring [here](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=0ab6651e369798de0dd2faae265ded08&mc=true&n=pt31.3.595&r=PART&ty=HTML#se31.3.595_1508). [Dept. of State](https://www.pmddtc.state.gov/embargoed_countries/) has a partial list of countries and their associated restrictions, if you want "like Gaza", and note that they warn you that this is not a complete list. If you are specifically interested in weapons-related restrictions, the US Munitions List is [here](https://www.pmddtc.state.gov/regulations_laws/documents/official_itar/ITAR_Part_121.pdf). There is no generic "anti-drone" system, so you would have to look at the specifics of a system to see if it is on the restricted list, or not.

Comment: The munitions link is to a state dept site for state dept employees.